# wget behaves differently with different adresses

Tags: wget

I have these two urls:

```
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/06/24/09/13/dog-2437110_960_720.jpg
```

and

```
http://www.deutschland-machts-effizient.de/SiteGlobals/KAENEF/StyleBundles/Bilder/sublogo.png;jsessionid=DF603F2801D8F686FD4BCFAD770C3FC9?__blob=normal&v=3
```

Trying to access the pictures with `wget` works for the first one, but does not for the second one. Of course the first more closely resembles a picture (ending in `.jpg`), but any browser I tested displayed both as pictures I could download.

Instead of a picture I download a 2000 line html file, which contains several `img` tags. I guess I could try any of the urls, but I want to automate this for a general case, so this doesn't really help me.

---

What is the inherent difference between both pictures in the way they are stored on their respective server?

How can I download the second picture using `wget`?

Comment: Does the second one give you a `png` image with the wrong filename (& extension)?

Comment: @byxor No it gives me an html file

Comment: When you go into the html, what's the URL of the image? Try to `wget` that URL instead.

Comment: @byxor See my edit. I'm sure I will get to the actual picture url at some point, but it doesn't really help my use case.

Comment: I'd happily add a small bounty to this question. I currently have no idea.

Comment: I would commend you for doing so